How to get entries with specific values in jupyter notebook/ python?
I have a dataframe containing some age group and health status. When I dropped entries not containing "RECOVERED" in "HealthStatus", the output is a table containing only the entries with "RECOVERED." But when I try this with "MODERATE," the table is empty. I checked the unique values for the HealthStatus column and it shows on the list that there are entries with "MODERATE" HealthStatus. Please help me.
I tried copy-pasting the code that worked for recovered but it still returns an empty table. I also tried to copy-paste the "MODERATE" word in case there are special characters but it still does not work.
Screenshot


change != -> == or 2. don't use drop func. boolean indexing is enough to filter. why filter and extract index and drop?


Hello! Thanks for this! I'm quite new to pandas and have not formally tackled it in college. I didn't realize that I can just use simpler functions.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

For selecting subset from dataframe use tutorial

